# How can I use a seller email address on my website instead of client-id

Tags: paypal

I am developing a web application where  I need to allow some vendors using my application sell their services.

I would like to integrate my app with PayPal express checkout. I ran into an issue where using express checkout requires the seller Client-ID.

In my case I am only allowed to get the sellers PayPal email address and not their PayPal Client-ID. How can I use their email instead of Client-ID to use PayPal express checkout?

Appreciate your help in advance

Kazem

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you are trying to Run an API call on behalf of the seller.
if you are taking some percentage out of it, you can consider using PayPal marketplace. (use to be adaptive payment)/